# jquery mobile accordion with image

Tags: image, listview, jquery-mobile, accordion

if go to **[this page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html)** you will find jquery mobile accordion. The problem with this accordion is that it is too simple. I want to make this accordin looks like list view by addind image instead of showing **+** or **-** sign. Could you please guide me for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icons by overriding the styles in your css stylesheet.

```
    .CollapsibleSetPage .ui-collapsible-set .ui-icon{
        background-image:url(images/icons-18-white.png)//your custom icon
    }
    .CollapsibleSetPage .ui-collapsible-set .ui-icon-plus{
        background-position:-108px
    }
    .CollapsibleSetPage .ui-collapsible-set .ui-icon-minus{
        background-position:-144px;
    }
```

I have added 'CollapsibleSetPage' class to he page to differentiate with other pages to override this behaviour.

Example with custom icons for collapsible set.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49735179/Stackoverflow/CustomCollapsibleIcons/test.html